# Bivariate Color symbology calculation when variables are at different scales

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I am visualizing the relationship between poverty rates (% below poverty line) at the neighborhood level and the number of hours food pantries are open. I am using the bivariate colors functionality to visualize this. There is a one to many relationship here: for each neighborhood, there are several food pantries. I want to make sure I understand exactly what is happening and my manual calculations haven't been helpful: is ArcGIS Pro taking an average across the food pantries and comparing that value to the neighborhood poverty? That is my gut assumption but I have to be certain. Is it taking the first value, or something else? I wasn't able to get a clear answer on this in the documentation, and I'd appreciate the help!